# How to sum up previous rows value's with current row in SAS?

Tags: sas

[image: Please see attached file]

I need a summation column, however, both retain and lag commando'es are inefficient.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please type the problem instead of linking an image, and also please show what you've done so far.

Comment: Show what you've tried with RETAIN or LAG - both could in theory work (RETAIN is better, I think).

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways. You could use **proc sql** or **proc means**. I've written a way below:

```
data begin;
    length person $3 sallary 5;
    input person sallary;
    datalines;
    a 200
    a 300
    b 800
    c 400
    c 500
    c 600
    ;
run;

proc means data=begin noprint; 
    by person; /*Handle each person as distinct subset*/
    output out=Sal_by_person(drop= _type_ _freq_) 
    sum(sallary)=Total_sallary /*What we calculate and what we call them.*/
    ;
run;
```